# Function template, disallowing certain types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a function template that must be allow only certain types. I've seen other questions but they used boost and primitve types. In this case, no boost, and it's a user defined class.

Ex:

```
template<typename T>
myfunc(T&)
{ ... }

template<>
myfunc(Foo&)
{
   static_assert(false, "You cannot use myfunc with Foo");
}
```

Problem is `static_assert` gets called regardless of whether I call `myfunc` with a `Foo` object or not.

I just want some way for compile to stop when `myfunc` is called with `Foo`.
How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: Your function has no return type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::is_same` for this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
return_type myfunc(T&)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<T, Foo>::value, "You cannot use myfunc with Foo");

   // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd `std::remove_const<T>` though. http://ideone.com/ebuud Or maybe `std::decay` it.

Comment: @Xeo yeah, I considered that, but decided to go for the same behaviour as the original. I'd probably use `Bare` though :P

Comment: What is `Bare`? A link is enough.

Comment: @n2liquid http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/05/29/type-traits-galore.html#bare_types

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: What's the advantage of `Bare` over `std::decay`?

Comment: @KerrekSB For this particular scenario, I believe there's no difference. But in general there is a difference: `std::decay` mimics what happens when you pass things by value; `Bare` strips references and cv-qualifiers. Most of the time the two are the same, but not always: `std::decay<int[3]>::type` is `int*`, while `Bare<int[3]>` is still `int[3]`. I'd pick `Bare` here because I find its meaning closer to what is intended.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Hmm.. I know about the *differences* between `Bare` and `decay`, but what's the *advantage*?

Answer (score 1):

With a return type `R`, say:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, Foo>::value, R>::type my_func(T &)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you really don't want to use the standard library, you can write the traits yourself:

```
template <bool, typename> struct enable_if { };
template <typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };

template <typename, typename> struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };
template <typename T> struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };
```

Comment: Since there are no actual overloads to be selected, a static assert is better because it gives better errors.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes one can never know. ADL will collect stuff from where the author of "my_func" didn't even dream of.